# Decide at runtime which class to invoke

Tags: java, design-patterns

Interface :

```
public interface Person {
public String name = "";
}
```

I have two classes:

```
public class Male implements Person {
public String name = "Male1";
}
```

Another class being

```
public class Female implements Person {
public String name = "Female";
}
```

I want to instantiate a class at runtime depending on who the user is. Something like :

```
Person p = getPerson("M");
System.out.println("P = " + p.name);

private static Person getPerson(String gender) {
    if (gender.equals("M"))
        return new Male();
    else if (gender.equals("F"))
        return new Female();
    else
        return null;
}
```

**I am expecting the output to be: Male1**
How can I achieve this ? What is the best design pattern to achieve this functionality ?

Comment: What you have is right. Look into the factory pattern.

Comment: When I execute this.. p.name is printing empty.. shen I debug it, it shows that it has the value but when I try to print it, its empty. Thoughts ?

Comment: Look into field hiding.

Comment: All the fields are public if you see..

Comment: You've declared a `name` field in the `Person` interface. This field, because it appears in an interface, is implicitly `static`. When you do `p.name` you are accessing that field, not the field of either of the `Person` implementations.

Comment: Exactly.. that is what is happening.. I want to know if there is any work around to achieve this functionality without introducing getters and setters ?

Comment: Not with interfaces. You can create an abstract class with a `protected` member, but you can't _redeclare_ that member in sub classes.

Comment: Hmm.. So there is no way to achieve this functionality without introducing getters for those variables ?

Comment: Read my comment again. Not with interfaces.

Comment: If you wont be able to redeclare the variable, how can we say at runtime use the variable from the class which has been instantiated ?

Comment: All subclasses inherit non-private instance variables. You can access them normally. However, if you redeclare a variable of the same name, you are _hiding_ the variable with the same name in the parent class.

Comment: public abstract class AbstractPerson {
 protected String gender = "AbstractPerson";
}

public class Male1 extends AbstractPerson {
 public String gender = "Male";
}

AbstractPerson person = new Male1();
System.out.println("P = " + person.gender);

Is giving "AbstractPerson"

Comment: It is actually hiding the sub class's member.

Comment: Yes because you are hiding it. Don't redeclare it.

Comment: You don't seem to understand what _declaring a variable_ is. Start by looking into that. Then look into what it means to _hide an instance variable_. Then look into what modifiers a variable declared in an interface will have. Then look into how instance variable access is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

lookup and use `Class.forName()`

Comment: I would not recommend this solution, its quite slow and difficult to maintain when refactoring.

Answer (score 0):

You don't put attributes in an interface.

Your interface should include a `String getName();` method signature. Then you implement this method in all inherited classes. That way, you can call `getName()` on your `Person` object to retrieve the person's name regardless of the implementation class.

To instantiate, take a look at the Factory pattern.

Answer (score 0):

There are several options, but you could use **Abstract Factory**:

Create a `PersonFactory` interface with just a `createPerson` method.  Then make two implementations:

1. `MaleFactory` which returns a new `Male`
2. `FemaleFactory` which returns a new `Female`

Then keep a `Map<String, PersonFactory>` where the key is the gender and the value is an instance of the factory that will create the appropriate `Person` instances.

Getting a new `Person` given the gender becomes as simple as

```
map.get(gender).createPerson()
```

**EDIT**:

I see you have edited your question so that it now includes a question about using variables in interfaces.

Basically, you don't want to put the variable in the interface, because that will mean it's static (the `static` keyword is implied in this case since interfaces can't have non-static variables), and I guess you don't want all persons to have the same name.

So you'll have to declare a `getName()` method in the interface.  If the behaviour should be the same for all genders (I don't see why not) then you can just put both the `name` variable and the `getName()` method in an abstract base class (e.g. `AbstractPerson`) which both `Male` and `Female` extend.

Comment: This way you can use the method in the interface. But how can you achieve the 'name' variable ? I can always put getters in the interface and make changes to the Male class. But the problem arises when you have to change the remaining classes which are dependent on Male class for the 'name' variable. They will have to be modified as well.